# Make items on an armor stand’s head invisible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-resource-packs, minecraft-data-packs

How do I make an item that is on a armor stand’s head invisible, but able to be seen by specific teams.  If an armor stand is invisible, any items in its slots is visible.  I want to have the items invisible to some players, but visible to other players.  Is this possible?  If any of this is unclear or you have any questions, please let me know.

Comment: Depending on now you are utilizing this you could try only have it show if a certain team is around - of course that means that someone else might see it though

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a full answer, but I know *for sure* that this is not possible in vanilla Minecraft.

Invisibility is controlled by the entity to make invisible, and is not configurable per player or per team.

The only way to make an entity invisible is to give it the Invisibility effect, or for armour stands, set its Invisibility data tag to `1b`.

You may want to consider downloading some mods/data packs, or creating your own. I'm not an expert at that, so I'm not the right person to ask for the job. You can look into these topics or wait for the next answer.